# Java: How to copy a graphics object and reuse it?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, graphics2d

I thought the create() function of graphics object creates a new copy of the current graphics object

this was my code

```
Graphics temp;
temp = g.create();
temp.drawString("hello world",100,100);
g.fillRect(200,200,50,50);
```

Now my understanding was that since temp is now a copy of the g, any change on temp would not be reflected on g. So my output should have been just a rectangle due to the fillRect function. But I am getting both the string and the rectangle on my paint output. Why is this happening and how to stop it?

Comment: it's the same physical drawing device, only the _state_ (like color, transform f.i.) is independent. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Also have a read on [Creating and Drawing to an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html)

Comment: I wanted to ave a copy of the graphics object on which subsequent changes wont be reflected on to the original object.

Right now I am doing that through an Image and inheriting its graphics. Just wanted to know if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: @CodeRed: `BufferedImage` may be used to compose images.

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner in java, but, after looking into your code i see that you have put 
g.create();
(i'm not very sure but) this could possibly mean that everything declare with g. would be affected. I suggest doing so:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
Graphics temp;
temp = g2d.create();
temp.drawString("hello world",100,100);
g.fillRect(200,200,50,50);
```

hope it worked

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make a class for the object, for example TextString and Box, and make them have a paint method like so:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```

And then wherever you are drawing the objects, call 
    box.paint(g); or whatever you called your object.

This way you can change the properties of the objects and draw them independently anytime you want without affecting the other objects.

Answer (score 0):

[Graphics.create](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#create()) gives you a full or specified section of the [Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object that generated it - it is not a new Graphics object.

If you wish to draw to a graphics object (and reuse said object) I would suggest using the [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) derivative, [OffscreenImage](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/awt/image/OffScreenImage.html) and, from there, draw to the [OffscreenImage.getGraphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics())